# .withColVis() is not working in angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, datatable, angular-datatables

when i try to use `.withColVis()` in angularjs datatable then `DTOptionsBuilder.fromSource(...).withPaginationType(...).withColVis is not a function` error generate.

check this plunker. [plunkr link](https://plnkr.co/edit/XNzdtOqK7f7XSA3DZtf9?p=preview)

If i use `.withDOM()` then it is working. 
check this [plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/qEOOQbuUxhufOMeKEyIT?p=preview)

I also take reference from official website [check this link](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/#!/overrideBootstrapOptions) :

help me to solve this problem , i want to use `.withColVis()` in my application.

`.withColVis()` is used for displaying a column list.

`.withColVis()` and `.withDOM('<"H"Cr>t<"F"ip>')` doing the same functionality , like displaying a `Show/Hide column` options. But `.WithDOM()` is working and `.withColVis()` is not working.

Not working code:

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('datatablesSampleApp', ['datatables']).
  controller('simpleCtrl', function($scope, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder) {
    $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromSource('data.json')
      .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
      // Active ColVis plugin
      .withColVis()
      // Add a state change function
      .withColVisStateChange(function(iColumn, bVisible) {
        console.log('The column' + iColumn + ' has changed its status to ' + bVisible)
      })
      // Exclude the last column from the list
      .withColVisOption('aiExclude', [2]);
    $scope.dtColumns = [
      DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('id').withTitle('ID'),
      DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('firstName').withTitle('First name'),
      DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('lastName').withTitle('Last name')
    ];
  });
})(angular);
```

Working Code:

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('datatablesSampleApp', ['datatables'])
    .controller('SimpleCtrl', SimpleCtrl);

  function SimpleCtrl(DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
      .withOption('sAjaxSource', 'data.json')
      .withDataProp('data')
      .withDOM('<"H"Cr>t<"F"ip>')
      .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
      .withDisplayLength(10);
    vm.dtColumns = [
      DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('id', 'ID'),
      DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('firstName', 'First name'),
      DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('lastName', 'Last name')
    ];

  }
})(angular);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *must* include `angular-datatables.colvis.js` in order to get the (now deprecated) `ColVis` plugin to work, here from the forked plnkr :

```js
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/v0.6.2/dist/plugins/colvis/angular-datatables.colvis.js"></script>
```

*and* inject the `datatables.colvis` module :

```js
angular.module('datatablesSampleApp', ['datatables', 'datatables.colvis']).
```

**https://plnkr.co/edit/edZcE3DLjaDSuNhTu2MV?p=preview**

Comment: it is possible to save state of visibility of columns ? , and render that states again when user visit back on that page?

Comment: @chiragsatapara, I dont know if you use `.withColVis` (it is deprecated, have never used it along with AD myself), but when I use `colvis` with **buttons** and `.withOption('stateSave', true)` then visible / hidden columns is "remembered" automatically, stored in localstorage on the local machine. I use it everywhere I use AD, multiple projects - so it defently works.

Comment: @chiragsatapara, you should really consider using "modern" `colvis` with buttons instead of the old module -> **http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/#!/withButtons** and as mentioned before it works with `stateSave` (perhaps the "old" `withColVis` does as well, but really dont know) .

Comment: you have a working plnkr of  `withButtons` ? Can you provide me that?

Comment: @chiragsatapara, see this -> **http://plnkr.co/edit/Y9BOkVHhpseVCLlTf7BR?p=preview** (if you not have figured it out already)